Ubuntu 24.04 mouse click always go to the desktop and not the app I'm using
I really wanted to give Ubuntu a chance for my current job, but I found that when I started installing apps like Oracle VirtualBox or Spotify and those apps were maximized, my mouse's clicks always went to the desktop instead the app I was trying to use.
Unfortunatelly, I had to go back to Windows simply because I can't work with this issue.
I was told by a work colleague that this could be related to Wayland on Gnome.
Has this happened to any of you? I'm using a B650M motherboard with a Ryzen 8700g and its integrated GPU.

Since you choose not to run Ubuntu I am confused why you would ask here. This is Ubuntu only support.

Because I do want to use Ubuntu and solve the issue I faced.

This question is similar to: Dysfunctional window controls in all my apps in Ubuntu 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I switched off in Settings-Desktop->Ubuntu Desktop->Panel mode and it seems the problem is gone.

